# Extract specified lines from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file and I want to extract specific lines from that file like lines 2, 10, 15,21, .... and so on. There are around 200 thousand lines to be extracted from the file. How can I do it efficiently in bash

Comment: make sure you search on internet Try and if unsucessful then show your code. SO is not meant for writing full codes for you

Comment: @Ashish. I asked stackoverflow because I was unsuccessful. I know naive way of doing it. If I knew the most efficient way, I wouldn't even be in the stackoverflow. So please stop this crap. Look at Dmitry Alexandrov, he really knows the efficient way to do it. Rather than spending hours figuring it out, I got decent help from Dmitry unlike you

Comment: Does that series (2, 10, 15, 21,...) go on like that until close to 200,000 or does it stop at around 100 or something ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe looking for:
sed -n -e 1p -e 4p afile

Comment: You can bump into command line length limit if you will try to filter out 200 000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Put the linenumbers of the lines you want in a file called "wanted", like this:

```
2
10
15
21
```

Then run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read w
do
   sed -n ${w}p yourfile
done < wanted
```

**TOTALLY ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

Or you could let "awk" do it all for you, like this which is probably miles faster since you won't have to create 200,000 sed processes:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=1;next}{if(FNR in a){print;}}' wanted yourfile
```

The FNR==NR portion detects when awk is reading the file called "wanted" and if so, it sets element "$1" of array "a" to "1" so we know that this line number is wanted. The stuff in the second set of curly braces is active when processing your bigger file only and it prints the current line if its  linenumber is in the array "a" we created when reading the "wanted" file.

Comment: Quite the same problem as with @Ashish’s approach. This is definitely the most inefficient solution. (It’s about first part of your answer.)

Comment: Please have a look at the alternative method I have added.

Comment: With 200,000 lines in "wanted" and 1,000,000 lines in "yourfile", the awk solution takes 2 seconds on my iMac. The bash+sed version will probably still be running on Friday!

Comment: Probably there is no better solution, but I think it may be written a bit clearly. One string is not enough, so I’ve posted it along with timings as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ gawk 'ARGIND==1 { L[$0]++ }; ARGIND==2 && FNR in L' lines file > file.lines
```

Wanted line numbers have to be stored in `lines` delimited by newline and they may safely be in random order. It almost exactly the same as @Mark Setchell’s second method, but uses a little more clear way to determine which file is current. Although this `ARGIND` is GNU extension, so `gawk`. If you are limited to original AWK or `mawk`, you can write it as:

```
$ awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1] { L[$0]++ }; FILENAME==ARGV[2] && FNR in L' lines file > file.lines
```

Efficiency test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=1000000; i++) print i }' > file
$ shuf -i 1-1000000 -n 200000 > lines
$ time gawk 'ARGIND==1 { L[$0]++ }; ARGIND==2 && FNR in L' lines file > file.lines

real    0m1.734s
user    0m1.460s
sys     0m0.052s
```

#### UPD:

As @Costi Ciudatu pointed out, there is room for impovement for the case when all wanted lines are in the head of a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

ARGIND==1 { L[$0]++ }
ENDFILE { L_COUNT = FNR }

ARGIND==2 && FNR in L { L_PRINTED++; print }
ARGIND==2 && L_PRINTED == L_COUNT { exit 0 }
```

Sript interrupts when last line is printed, so now it take few milliseconds to filter out 2000 random lines from first 1 % of a one million lines file.

```
$ time ./getlines.awk lines file > file.lines

real    0m0.016s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
```

While reading a whole file still takes about a second.

```
$ time gawk 'ARGIND==1 { L[$0]++ }; ARGIND==2 && FNR in L' lines file > file.lines

real    0m0.780s
user    0m0.756s
sys     0m0.016s
```

Comment: Or just the traditional `NR==FNR` which is true only for the first input file.

Comment: @tripleee Yes. But I posted it only to show how not to use `NR==FNR`, which is quite obscure I think. There is no any other essential differences from Mark Setchell’s answer.

Comment: Dmitry, I don't really appreciate you proposing a solution which is pretty much exactly the same as mine by your OWN admission, which you claim adds timings which I already had provided too, and which, unhelpfully in my opinion, requires a more specific version of awk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Should I delete this answer?

Comment: Dmitry, No, it's ok - I guess it does add something. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Provided your system supports `sed -f -` (i.e. for `sed` to read its script on standard input; it works on Linux, but not on some other platforms) you can turn the file of line numbers into a `sed` script, naturally using `sed`:

```
sed 's/$/p/' lines | sed -n -f - inputfile >output
```

Comment: How long it have been take to filter 200 000 lines of 1 000 000 line file? I’ve lost patience and interrupted execution after 20 second.

Comment: Good question. Anybody want to do timings?

Answer (score 0):

If the lines you're interested in are close to the beginning of the file, you can make use of `head` and `tail` to efficiently extract specific lines.

For your example line numbers (assuming that list doesn't go on until close to 200,000), a dummy but still efficient approach to read those lines would be the following:

```
for n in 2 10 15 21; do
    head -n $n /your/large/file | tail -1
done
```

Comment: I thought @Ashnish suggest the most inefficient solution. No, your one is four times worse, since there is four processes per one line (`head`, `tail` and two subshells).

Comment: @DimitryAlexandrov: If by efficiency you mean time of execution, I think you should avoid reading the whole file at all costs (it's worth spawning even 10 processes for reading each line if those processes will only have to read around 10-100 lines). A solution that reads the whole file (once in a single process) will only be more efficient in terms of process ID economy, but it will run orders of magnitude slower. But again, it only fits in if you need to read lines in the first 1-5% of the file.

Comment: No, it does not fit even for the first 0.1 % of the file. `$ shuf -i 1-1000 -n 200 > lines` (200 random lines of the first 0.1 % of a one million lines file), `$ time while read; do head -n $REPLY file | tail -1 >> file.lines; done < lines` / `real    0m3.259s` / `user    0m0.112s` / `sys     0m3.452s` So it takes more time than reading the whole file.

Comment: OK, you win! :) For the record, how long did it take to read the whole file (with your solution) in your above-mentioned test ? However, you got my upvote for your answer ;)

Comment: Still about a second. You are certainly right – it would be a substantial improvement if we will read input file no further than it’s necessary – so I updated my answer and I would be glad if you have a look.

Answer (score -1):

sed Example

```
sed -n '2p' file
```

awk Example

```
awk 'NR==2' file
```

this will print 2nd line of file

use same logic in loop & try.

say a for loop

```
for VARIABLE in 2 10 15 21 
  do
    awk "NR==$VARIABLE" file

 done
```

Give your line numbers this way..

Comment: I can’t call this the efficient solution. You read a file from the start to the end four times and create five processes to extract four lines.